# how can i get a css table-cell link not to stretch the clickable area

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a banner of links at the top of the page that may or may not at some point we replaced with objects or images or differing sizes. so i am not using a list, nor a table, i am simply writing out the text and setting classes to split the objects up as if they were in a table.

```
<a href="#" class="left"> Link 1 </a> <a href="#" class="middle"> Link 2</a> <a href="#" class="right">Link 3</a>

.left{display:table-cell;min-width:150px;min-height:25px;}
.middle{display:table-cell;min-width:150px;min-height:25px;}
.right{display:table-cell;min-width:150px;min-height:25px;}
```

However, When i do this my link is maybe 50px of text but the clickable area is 125px. How can i get the link to be clickable ONLY on the link?

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FYELm/1/)

Comment: no that will not work, i must have a min-width set in this instance.

Comment: you're setting a min-width on your clickable anchor so that is why it is clickable beyond the text.  But yet you say you need a min-width. Do you mean you need defined spacing?

Comment: yes, need at least x amount of space. Answer below to wrap in span tags works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should nest your link into spans, and apply table-cell style in spans.

Something like this:

```
<span class="left"><a href="#">Link 1</a></span>
<span class="middle"><a href="#">Link 2</a></span>
<span class="right"><a href="#">Link 3</a></span>
```

See this forked [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw6xp/)

Comment: Nice ! would you mind closing your question ? thanks !

Comment: I meant to, then i finished work and i forgot about it. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block not table-cell.  Set width to auto.  Use margin if you need spacing

```
.left
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
    min-height:25px;
}
.middle
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 2em;
    min-height:25px;
}
.right
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    min-height:25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FYELm/5/

Comment: This looked ok at first glace, But i cna't have margins nor padding simply because we don't know what will occupy that position, maybe a picture, maybe text, or something else.